# Does the lualatex shell enable behavior differ from pdflatex on purpose?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, shell-escape

I am trying to use TikzEdt, an editor for TikZ graphics. For some tasks TikZ needs to call other commands so I tried to enable this by the parameter `--shell-escape` passed to `lualatex` (on Windows, MiKTeX 2.9). Strangely this fails to enable the feature. After some fiddling around it turns out that it even fails with this MWE:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \begin{document}
    \write18{echo SHELL ENABLED}
    \end{document}
```

TikzEdt appends the switch and calls `lualatex test.tex --shell-escape` which does not seem to work. The same command with pdflatex works nicely. It turns out that other than in pdflatex the order of arguments seem to play a role in lualatex, `lualatex --shell-escape test.tex` runs nicely. Unfortunately TikzEdt only allows to append switches not insert switches. Is this a bug in lualatex or is TikzEdt using a wrong assumption?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, everything that goes after the filename is treated as a command. As the `--help` flag gives us the hint, "Any remaining `COMMANDS` are processed as pdfTeX input, after `TEXNAME` is read. If the first line of `TEXNAME` is `%&FMT`, and `FMT` is an existing `.fmt` file, use it.  Else use `NAME.fmt`, where `NAME` is the program invocation name,
most commonly `pdftex`."

Comment: By the way, my test was consistent here with both `pdflatex` and `lualatex` (I got the same results), so flags really should come before the filename. `:)`

Comment: Probably it is another MiKTeX feature; commandline parsing is not done by support code from the Web2c system (and its equivalent in MiKTeX), except probably for LuaTeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's try a simple document `test.tex`; the package `pdftexcmds` is loaded in order to have `\pdf@shellescape` available with all engines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\count@=\pdf@shellescape
\showthe\count@
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Ciao
\end{document}
```

Here's what happens with

- `pdflatex test`
- `pdflatex test --shell-escape`
- `lualatex test`
- `lualatex test --shell-escape`
- `xelatex test`
- `xelatex test --shell-escape`

The execution stops because of `\showthe`, showing

```
> 2.
l.5 \showthe\count@
```

in all six invocations (TeX Live 2012 on Mac OS X, but I don't think it's different with other platforms).

If we put `--shell-escape` at its proper place, the execution of any of

- `pdflatex --shell-escape test`
- `lualatex --shell-escape test`
- `xelatex --shell-escape test`

stops showing

```
> 1.
l.5 \showthe\count@
```

This means that the setting of `--shell-escape` can be done *only* in "infix notation" and that the option has *no* effect if postfixed.

As kindly as usual, Paulo Cereda confirms that, on MiKTeX, options can be specified after the file name for `pdftex` and `xetex`, but not for `luatex`. As the most common syntax format on other systems is with "infix" options, my opinion is that TikZEdt is wrong in its assumptions.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be different here. Your example document stops and shows `\showthe\count@` with both, `lualatex --shell-escape example` and `pdflatex --shell-escape example` on MikTeX 2.9. I really dislike these strange incompatibilities.

Comment: @Alexander My opinion is that it's best to stick to the most common "cross platform" way of doing things. For instance, MiKTeX adopted `--shell-escape` after having used `--enable-write18` for some years.

Comment: Yes egreg, I absolutely agree. I looked up the POSIX guidelines and they state that option processing stops after the first command, so according to what you observe.

Comment: @mafp Yes. I should've made it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

the syntax of `luatex` (`lualatex`) is

```
Usage: luatex --lua=FILE [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: luatex --lua=FILE [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
   or: luatex --lua=FILE [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
```

`--shell-escape` is an option the reason why it must be before the  `TEXNAME[.tex]`