# Does --no-shell-escape break \pdf@shellescape?

Tags: luatex, shell-escape, command-line

**Edit:** since posting the question I've fixed a few mistakes. I don't think they affect the answer given below, but I wanted to correct the record for completeness.

## Background

I have a Python script which calls `lualatex` to generate lots of short standalone documents. Being paranoid and trying to learn good habits, I use [`subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) and `--no-shell-escape` to make sure my call to `lualatex` doesn't do anything out of the ordinary. The script runs fine at work, but at home `lualatex` encounters an error and returns a nonzero return code. This error doesn't occur if I omit `--no-shell-escape` from the options list.

It would be nice to understand why this is the case!
Can any TeX.SE residents shed some light?

## MWE

Here's a test snippet written by egreg [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96718/82389).

```
%From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96718/82389
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\count@=\pdf@shellescape
\showthe\count@
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Ciao
\end{document}
```

If I save the above as `test.tex` and run `lualatex --no-shell-escape test` at work, it reports

```
work $ lualatex --no-shell-escape test.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013121407 (rev 4627) 
[...output trimmed...]
> 0.
l.6 \showthe\count@
```

If I run the same command at home, however, the following happens.

```
home $ lualatex --no-shell-escape test.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
[...output trimmed...]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.5 \count@=\pdf@shellescape

? 
> 0.
l.6 \showthe\count@
```

In particular, I get an error where there was none before.

I'm not sure what's going on, and would be interested to find out more.

## Other information

### Version numbers

At work:

- LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013121407  (TeX Live 2013/dev/Debian) (rev 4627)
- pdftexcmds Version: 2011/11/29 v0.20

```
work $ luatex --version | head -n 1
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013121407  (TeX Live 2013/dev/Debian) (rev 4627)
work $ locate pdftexcmds.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
work $ kpsewhich pdftexcmds.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
work $ grep 'Version:' < `kpsewhich pdftexcmds.sty`
%% Version: 2011/11/29 v0.20
```

At home:

- LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
- pdftexcmds Version: 2017/03/19 v0.25.
- **NB.** In the original post, I mistakenly thought that the version was v0.20 at home as well. This is incorrect. It seems I have more than one installation of texlive, and thankfully luatex is using the more recent version of the style file.

```
home $ luatex --version | head -n 1
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
home $ locate pdftexcmds.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
home $ kpsewhich pdftexcmds.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
home $ grep 'Version:' < $(kpsewhich pdftexcmds.sty)
%% Version: 2017/03/19 v0.25
```

### The definition of `\pdf@shellescape`

At work (`pdftexcmds` v0.20) the definition of `\pdf@shellescape` is

```
\ifnum\luatexversion<68 %
\else
  \def\pdf@shellescape{%
    \directlua0{%
      oberdiek.pdftexcmds.shellescape()%
    }%
  }%
\fi
```

At home (`pdftexcmds` v0.25) of pdftexcmds, it's defined as

```
\ifnum\luatexversion<68 %
\else
  \protected\edef\pdf@shellescape{%
   \numexpr\directlua{tex.sprint(status.shell_escape)}\relax}
\fi
```

At the time of writing, the latter definition is also present in the current version of `pdftexcmds`. The implementation seems to be discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/20).

### Misc

If I run `lualatex --shell-escape test.tex`, `\count@` is printed as 1.
If I run `lualatex test.tex`, `\count@` is printed as 2.
In both scenarios I don't get any TeX errors.
The two commands behave the same at both work and home.

Comment: The lualatex versions are quite different. You can only compare the same package and engine versions.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The package versions are already the same. If the engine versions were the same, wouldn't I expect identical results on both machines?

Comment: both of those luatex versions are _very_ old beta versions, there have been multiple changes in luatex  (which is already at 1.07 in texlive and 1.09 in development releases) (although that may not affect this issue)

Comment: @daleif I've just noticed I was wrong about the home version of `pdftexcmds` and have corrected the original post. So my previous comment was incorrect: both the luatex and package versions are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it does...

I think this is a bug in the newer version of `pdftexcmds` that wasn't in the older version (either way, you should update your distribution :).

`pdftexcmds` defines `\pdf@shellescape` with:

```
\ifnum\luatexversion<68 %
\else
  \protected\edef\pdf@shellescape{%
   \numexpr\directlua{tex.sprint(status.shell_escape)}\relax}
\fi
```

which will make something like `\numexpr 0\relax`.

But if, after you load `pdftexcmds`, you say `\show\pdf@shellescape`, you'll see (running with the `--no-shell-escape` flag):

```
> \pdf@shellescape=\protected macro:
->\numexpr \relax .
```

which raises the `! Missing number, treated as zero.` error.

This happens because earlier in the code, `pdftexcmds` has:

```
\ifnum\luatexversion<36 %
\else
  \catcode`\0=9 %
\fi
```

which makes `0` be an ignored character. With this catcode regime, the `0` returned disappears, and invalidates the `\pdf@shellescape` macro.

The older version of `pdftexcmds` didn't have this issue because `\pdf@shellescape` wasn't created with `\edef`, but with `\def`, so when the macro was used, the `\catcode` of `0` was correct:

```
\ifnum\luatexversion<68 %
\else
  \def\pdf@shellescape{%
    \directlua0{%
      oberdiek.pdftexcmds.shellescape()%
    }%
  }%
\fi
```

To fix this you can simply re-define the `\pdf@shellescape` in the same way after `pdftexcmds` is loaded, except that now `0` won't be ignored:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\ifnum\luatexversion<68 %
\else
  \protected\edef\pdf@shellescape{%
   \numexpr\directlua{tex.sprint(status.shell_escape)}\relax}
\fi
\count@=\pdf@shellescape
\showthe\count@
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Ciao
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the analysis, I'm travelling so can't look at this straight away, but if you could drop an issue at https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues I'd be grateful!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done. You're welcome :)

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik @DavidCarlisle I just wanted to point out that I was mistaken about the version of `pdftexcmds` I was using at home. I've updated the original post; I don't think this affects what Phelype wrote at all, but I wanted to mention it for completeness.

Comment: @DavidR No problem :) I thought so, because I could reproduce the issue (with both the working older version and the newer one, with this feature) here, and the error message you showed was pointing towards that conclusion, I wrote my answer based on that :)